# Unable to get the updated table values when jquery is used to get the html() attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which is loaded from database. When a user updates the text boxes in the table, i have written a jquery which should collect the updated values from the HTML table and wanted to update them back to database. Need help in fixing the jquery to get the updated values from the form. Below written Jquery doesn't give me updated html values when i fill a form and try to run the Jquery.

**HTML**

```
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm" cellspacing="10" width="100%" style="font-size: 14px; height: auto">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr style="text-align: right;">
                                        <th>Key Type</th>
                                        <th>Key</th>
                                        <th>Value</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {% for result in results %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{result["Key Type"]}}</td>
                                        <td>{{result["Key"]}}</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" value={{result["Value"]}} style="text-align: center;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="submit" id="Save" align="center" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px" value="SAVE">
                                <input type="reset" id="Reset" align="center" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px" value="CANCEL">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var dataArr = [];
        $("td").each(function () {
            dataArr.push($(this).html());
        });
        $('#Save').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                url: "/SaveFile",
                data: JSON.stringify(dataArr),
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (response, error) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Changes Made**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Save').click(function () {
            var dataArr = [];
            $("td").each(function () {
                dataArr.push($(this).html());
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                url: "/SaveFile",
                data: JSON.stringify(dataArr),
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (response, error) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't appear to update your table, nor appear to obtain updated information. It's unclear to me what your issue is. It also appears that what you have labeled as HTML is not actually HTML, but is expected to be processed into HTML through some other program. Please provide us with accurate information to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: If what you're saying is that you expect the `dataArr` array to be the current contents of each `<td>` at the time you click `'#Save'`, then, obviously, it won't be. It will be the contents at the time when the `dataArr` is created, given that `dataArr` is never updated in the code you've shown. If you want it to be the `<td>` contents at the time `'#Save'` is clicked, then you need to read the data at that time. This could be trivially accomplished by moving the `$('#Save').click(function () {` line to immediately after the `$(function () {` line.

Comment: Still have the same issue. let me edit the code change made

Answer (score 0):

I would consider an Array of Objects versus a single Array. If your Table is in this format:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm" cellspacing="10" width="100%" style="font-size: 14px; height: auto">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: right;">
        <th>Key Type</th>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for result in results %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{result["Key Type"]}}</td>
        <td>{{result["Key"]}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" value={{result["Value"]}} style="text-align: center;"></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="submit" id="Save" align="center" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px" value="SAVE">
    <input type="reset" id="Reset" align="center" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px" value="CANCEL">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then an Array will contain just a giant list of hard to read data.

Consider the following.

```
function getTableData(tbl){
  var head = $("thead", tbl);
  var body = $("tbody", tbl);
  var results = [];
  var keys = [];
  var row;
  $("th", head).each(function(i, el){
    keys.push($(el).text().trim());
  });
  $("tr", body).each(function(ri, r){
    row = {};
    $.each(keys, function(i, k){
      if(i < 2){
        row[k] = $("td", r).eq(i).text().trim();
      } else {
        row[k] = $("td", r).eq(i).find("input").val();
      }
    });
    results.push(row);
  });
  return results;
}
```

This will give you a more structured dataset. For example, using it like so:

```
var dataObj = getTableData($("#myTable"));
```

The `dataObj` array would contain something like:

```
[
  {
    "Key Type": "Number",
    "Key": "Product Code",
    "Key Value": "1001"
  },
  {
    "Key Type": "Number",
    "Key": "Product Code",
    "Key Value": "1002"
  }
]
```

Also notice for some cells, we're getting the Text from that cell and the final cell, we have to get the Value from the Input field. If that's the only item you're trying to get an array of, you can simplify the code.

```
function getTableData(tbl){
  var body = $("tbody", tbl);
  var results = [];
  $("tr", body).each(function(i, r){
    results.push($("td:last input", r).val());
  });
  return results;
}
```

This will give you an array of all the Inputs. It would be used like:

```
var dataArr = getTableData($("#myTable"));
```